# Trojan FakeLook.A prevents compiling in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm currently trying to compile a project in Android Studio, but it does not want to compile. I'm getting an error message indicating that there is a virus or PUP in the generated code, and that Android Studio therefore can't continue compiling.

While looking in Windows Defender's history, I get the following:

[image: Trojan FakeLook.A]

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the generated .dex files of the library `JSch`, as seen in the path name: Y:...\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\**jsch**-0.1.53_05559622e5c446db6959df99d64c725274c702f3\classes.dex

It is mentioned in Google Issue Tracker by Issue 206229. It is a false positive that seems to only be generated by Windows Defender.

The solution to this issue is to submit the file on https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/portal/submission/submit.aspx to make Microsoft recognize it as a false-positive and remove it from it's virus definitions.

Two possible workarounds are either temporarily disabling Windows Defender or switching to a different OS such as Linux.